# Unable to Upload Video with p-fileUpload of Primeng

Tags: angular, primeng

I am unable to upload a video file using p-fileUpload of primeng when i click on Choose Button :-

The Code is present here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-upkjow-55jrqn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Did anyone face an issue like this?

Answer (score 1):

> accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg, .mp3 ,.mkv, .mp4"

Please remove spaces as mentioned below

```
accept="image/.png,.jpg,.jpeg,.mp3,.mkv,.mp4"
```